# How can I stack request calls so they don't complete until one is finished?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an array of items that I need to post to my server. I've tried the following but `i` never iterates.

```
var i = 0;
while (i < numOfItems) {
    var item = items[i];
    var a;
    for(var ik in item){
        console.log(item[ik]);
        a = item[ik]; // Gets the key
        break;
    }        

    var formData = {
        ID : ID,
        UID : UID,
        item : a
    }
    request.post({url:'http://example.com/a', formData: formData}, function(err, httpResponse, body){ 
        if (err) {
            return console.error('Post failed:', err);
        }
        console.log('Post successful!  Server responded with:', body);
        i++;
    });
}
```

Comment: just curious, why the `break` in your `for`loop? Apart, who is that `request` object?

Comment: @Manu Prevents `a` from being `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't work because `request.post` is asynchronous. If your objective is to make a call for each element in the array, a working and a more elegant solution would be to use [`Promises.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Here's your code modified with Promises —

```
function postRequest(url, formData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.post({ url, formData }, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
            if (!error) {
                resolve({ message: 'Post successful!', response: body });
            } else {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    })
}

// Map your data array to an array of Promises
let promises = yourArray.map(element => {
    let formData = {
        ID: ID,
        UID: UID,
        item: element
    }
    return postRequest({ url: 'http://example.com/a', formData: formData })
});

// Wait for all Promises to complete
Promise.all(promises)
    .then(results => {
        // Handle results
    })
    .catch(e => {
        // Handle error
    });
```

A few things to note -

1. I'm reusing the fields `ID` and `UID` as-is, as it isn't clear where they come from in your code.
2. Replace `yourArray` with the array containing your data items.

Comment: Should it work if I don't use let? I can't use `--use_strict` because of Firebase. I get the error `ReferenceError: error is not defined` when I use `var` instead of `let`. `/a` is never called.

Comment: You can use `var` instead of `let`, sure. Just make sure you read a bit about `let`, as it is great!